# Am using tryparse, but still getting crashes

Tags: c#, tryparse

I have been working through http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/csharp/csharp_s3p9.html and written a simple loop multiplication tool and wanted to add the tryparse to stop crashes with blanks.

However, I still get a crash if I leave the first box blank with the following code:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication4
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int loopStart = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
            int loopEnd = int.Parse(textBox2.Text);
            int multiply = int.Parse(textBox3.Text);
            int answer = 0;
            listBox1.Items.Clear();
            int firstNum = 0;
            bool isNumber = int.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out firstNum);

            if (!isNumber)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("bah");
            }
            else            
            {
                for (int i = loopStart; i <= loopEnd; i++)
                {
                    answer = multiply * i;
                    listBox1.Items.Add(i + " times " + multiply + 
                                         " = " + answer.ToString());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone help explain why?  I have looked on multiple sites (main reason the bool code is slightly different) but can't seem to make it work.  This is if I leave box1 blank but enter numbers in to the other 2.

I see that I have down votes - I am unsure why as this is my first time here and i'm a beginner coder - maybe my questions seem rather basic.  I am not complaining, I am genuingly intersted in knowin what i've done wrong so that I don't repeat the mistake in future as i'm sure I will be back here a few times.

Thank you for the replies below, very helpful to me.

Answer (score 2):

You are not using `TryParse`, you are using `Parse` method before first `TryParse` call which is throwing the exception.Change your `Parse` calls to `TryParse` then check the result of each of them.

```
int loopStart,loopEnd,multiply;  

if(int.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out loopStart) &&
   int.TryParse(textBox2.Text, out loopEnd)
   int.TryParse(textBox3.Text, out multiply))
{
    // parsing successfull
}
```

Comment: Excellent - that seems to of stopped the crashing.  I cannot quite see why though.  I understand it's saying what to do if it comes back with a true number, however I do not see how it is saying 'if there isn't a valid number, do nothing (ie, do not fail)'

Answer (score 1):

As everyone has stated, you are using `Parse` before `TryParse`, which is why its breaking. I don't think you're understanding what `TryParse` does. `TryParse` is a 2-in-1 short cut. Doing this:

```
int loopStart = 0;
bool isLoopStartNumber = int.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out loopStart);
```

is exactly equivalent to this:

```
int loopStart = 0;
bool isLoopStartNumber = false;
try {
    loopStart = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
    isLoopStartNumber = true;
} catch {
    isLoopStartNumber = false;
}
```

As you can see, `TryParse` provides a much cleaner and simpler way to do the latter. Two lines of code versus 8 lines. In addition, `TryParse` suppresses throwing an actual exception, which makes it faster then the latter.

Comment: I hope that I'm not being too picky, but it is not exactly equivalent. It is functionally equivalent. The TryParse method never actually throws an exception. That makes it quite a bit faster (and simpler to use).

Comment: @KevinS -- You are correct and I modified my answer to reflect it.

Answer (score 0):

It crashes because you are still using `Parse` in your code on something that is not an `int`, like blank?

Remove:

```
int loopStart = int.Parse(textBox1.Text)
```

And just use `TryParse`